# SSO between a ASP.net web app and PowerApps portal application using Azure AD B2C authentication

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, powerapps

We have an existing ASP.net web application that uses Azure AD B2C for authentication. The sign in policy used is set for SSO (across B2C Tenant).
We have configured another PowerApps portal application that uses the same sign in user flow to authenticate. (Tutorial used : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/azure-ad-b2c)

Requirement is that above two application should be able to use SSO. i.e. If I am signed in on the ASP.net app and I re-direct to PowerApps, I should be automatically signed in.

Currently upon redirecting to PowerApps's login ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwi8W.png)) I am asked to sign in again.

What can be done so that the redirection is seamless and user is automatically signed in to PowerApps application?

Comment: If you click the AAD B2C Button in your screenshot, are you asked for credentials again?

Comment: No, clicking on the adb2c button logs the user in using the existing cookie... I required that the hser shouldn't have to press that button. Turns out all that needed to be done was to use only one authentication in the power apps portal. That way, the user is signed in as soon as he is redirected to the power app